# Is testing implementation correct when designing class calling external API?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I started out with some prototype code that goes along these lines:

```
// Omitted most definitions, return values checks, etc.
// The real code is much bigger and uglier.
serverId = socket(AD_INET, SOCK_STREAM, PROTO_ANY);
setsockopt(serverId, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuseAddrOk, sizeof(int));
bind(serverId, &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
listen(serverId, waitQueueSize);
clientId = accept(serverId, &clientAddress, sizeof(clientAddress));
read(clientId, clientBuffer, charsToRead);
```

Now I'd like to refactor this code extracting functionality in very simple classes (not trying to make things very generic for now...YAGNI). This is the kind of interface I'm thinking of:

```
SocketServer server = SocketServer(parameters);
// SocketServer knows how to create a SocketClient...abstract factories, dependency injection, etc. etc.
SocketClient client = server.accept();
string clientMessage = client.read();
client.write(serverMessage);
```

For instance, the `SocketServer` class encapsulates all the boilerplate for creating a new socket server:

```
SocketServer server = SocketServer(parameters);
```

Then, since this need to call the system API, I need to mock it:

```
SocketServer server = SocketServer(systemAPI, parameters);
```

Now, what does it mean testing that this code is correct? It doesn't produce any output that I can check (or better, I'm doing all of this exactly to encapsulate output, like file descriptors). I could check that the correct methods of the mock API are called, like:

```
testSocketCalledWithCorrectParameters() {
    systemAPI = mock(SystemAPI).expect(once()).method("socket").with(
        SystemAPI.AF_INET,
        SystemAPI.SOCK_STREAM,
        SystemAPI.PROTO_AUTO
    );
    ServerSocket(systemAPI, parameters);
}
```

Is this a proper situation where I should rely on testing an implementation instead of an interface? Is being forced to test an implementation rather than an interface smelling of bad design?

All other tests I could think of set expectations about the implementation:

```
testServerSocketIsCreatedWithCorrectDescriptor() {
    dummyDescriptor = 10;
    systemAPI = mock(SystemAPI).when("socket").return(dummyDescriptor);
    server = SocketServer(systemAPI, parameters);
    assertEquals(dummyDescriptor, server.descriptor);
}

/**
 * @expected SocketException
 */
testThrowsExceptionIfErrorCreatingSocket() {
    systemAPI = mock(SystemAPI).when("socket").return(SystemAPI.RETURN_ERROR);
    SocketServer(systemAPI, parameters);
}

// etc.
```

And then, should I write unit tests also for the `socketAPI`, or should I just take for granted that it will be a very dumb wrapper class, doing nothing more than delegating calls to the external API (and thus it won't need to be tested)?

Comment: If `X` is supposed to do `Y` when when provide `Z`, how would you test it? You will call `X`, providing `Y` and test the result for `Z`. If you can't, you need to write the basic infrastructure which will allow you to do so.

Comment: "*testing an implementation instead of an interface*" - what would it mean to test an interface?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth If I have a function `add(a, b)` I can test that `add(1,2) == 3` and `add(10,1) == 11`, regardless of how this function is implemented.

Comment: @EugeneSh. By "basic infrastructure which will allow you to do so" you mean the test framework functions like "expect that this method will be called n-times", or a different design of the SUT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to answer one by one.

**1. Testing call properties**

This kind of test has only documentational value (This is the way to call the API.) Check, if it is really worth it -> maybe the statement is clear enough in your code.

**2. testServerSocketIsCreatedWithCorrectDescriptor**:

For me this kind of test have more value. I almost always write a testCreation which shows: input parameters and asserts properties, e.g. a car needs wheel for construction and has then 4 wheels, red colour and one steering wheel by default.

**3. testThrowsExceptionIfErrorCreatingSocket**

This kind of tests are the most valuable. They define and protect behaviour of your class on different circumstances. I'm missing an assertion here, e.g. the kind of exception, which is thrown.
Write as much as thinkable of this kind of tests.

**4. Testing systemAPI**

No. Never test system behaviour in unit tests. Especially not with mocks.
This is part of module or end to end tests.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What do you mean by "Testing call properties"? Testing that certain methods of the mock are called a certain amount of times? In case 2, do you think it's worth to expose properties that would normally be hidden (as part of the implementation) only for testing purposes? Agreed on focusing more on testing exceptional circumstances.

Comment: Yes, I meant testing that certain methods on a mock are called, and which arguments are passed. In case 2: you meant revealing server.descriptor for testing purposes only - Not a good idea. My tip: Listen to your tests, they often reveal serious design flaws. If testing is hard and creepy - it's your design, not the test's fault